# Postgres data with interval of 8 hours

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a table with large number of rows. It has column like timestamp(in millis), value, and a siteId(foreign key). I want to fetch data from that of last three months with an interval in timestamp of 8 hours and I want to fetch data of all `siteId` in the three month timestamp. I have data in there for every 5 minutes of every siteId. If I fetch data of last three months, it is coming in millions. so I want to take data of every 8 hours. Sometimes, there can be a gap too so if a `siteId` was not there for the 8th hour, it should get its next data which can be 5 minutes past(or 10minutes past...) of that 8th hour.

Its hard  to create a query for that and normal fetching and massaging the data in afterwards will take time.

I am using postgres, java and JPA. If I can do it via query or via some JPA utility to ease the CPU? I want to drop the time taken(right now 9 seconds for each query) to the least. Can you guys help me? Thanks in advance

My Table structure:

```
    | timestamp      | value | siteId |
    |----------------|-------|--------|
    | 1610370000000  | 22    | 123    |
    | 1610370700000  | 21    | 123    | 
    | 1610370028000  | 22    | 123    |
    | 1610369889000  | 23    | 123    |
    | 1610370000000  | 22    | 124    |
    | 1613534400000  | 21    | 124    |
    | 1610369889000  | 22    | 124    |
    | 1610370005000  | 23    | 125    |
```

So every site is having data for every 5 minutes. I want data of last three months with interval of at least 8 hours of every site. Hope this helps

Comment: Please add some sample data, table structure and desired output. It will help to understand your problem. creating query is not that much hard. you can use [online tools](https://dbfiddle.uk/) for demonstration

Comment: What does interval of at least 8 hours mean?

Comment: Just in case if it is useful to you. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-rank-function/ . Somehow you would need to create partition and use first element from that partition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the data i have is with interval of 5 minutes(the site sends me data every 5 minutes), i want to fetch the data from the same table, data with one reading for every 8 hours.

Comment: And what would those results look like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want same data structure like your example in question from last 3 months on 8 hours interval for each siteID.

Try this:

```
select 
distinct on (siteId, "group" ) siteId, value, timestamp_,
ceil((extract(epoch from current_timestamp)*1000-timestamp_)/28800000) "group" 
from test
where to_timestamp(timestamp_/1000) between current_timestamp - interval '3 month' and current_timestamp
order by 1,4,3
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1d9807baee21460373f593d00706655c)

Here I am dividing the difference of `current_timestamp` and `timestamp_` field with `2880000(8*60*60*1000)` to get the `group` and getting the first value of the group by using `distinct on`.

You can switch order by from `order by 1,4,3` (return the value of min timestamp_ of range) to `order by 1,4,3 desc` (return the value of max timestamp_ of range) to check the correct result.
I am not sure about performance. But is should work better than java fetching.

Comment: When i am using JPA query, it takes around 9 seconds and  fetch me almost a million data which i filter afterwards in java. The whole process takes around 10-11 seconds. When i am using your query, it itself is taking somewhere around 39 seconds. And i do need to massage data afterwards anyway. I am sorry but your solution did not help me. thank you so much though

Answer (score 0):

If you need all data but you face issue with a transfer of huge data amount I would recommend to use pagination approach.
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pagination